# Adding a html element in a string in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know this is not the React way of doing things but it's something i need and i just wanna try a solution.

After an action in my page, i display a JSON with

```
JSON.stringify(myJSON, null, 4);
```

This change triggers the `render` in my class.

Inside this json i have a timestamp value, that i translate into readable time. I do this before stringifying, like this:

```
myJson.timestamp = `${myJson.timestamp} ( ${newDate(parseInt(myJson.timestamp) * 1000)} )`
```

Now comes the weird stuff:
I need to have a button right next to this translated timestamp. In the previous version of my app i was doing this easily like this:

```
myJson.timestamp = myJson.timestamp + "( " + newDate(parseInt(myJson.timestamp) * 1000) + " ) <button>action!</button>"
```

which rendered my button in the page.

But react just writes it as a string, without rendering it. I guess this happens because ReactDOM doesn't parse that as a new HTML element because `render` is not triggered anywhere.

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this in react and how. As you can see it's pretty complicated to try to render the button in that place the react way and i have no idea how to actually do it.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://codesandbox.io/s/vvz516nyr0

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac that was exactly what i needed! I have seen `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` while googling but i wasn't really sure if it's what i needed. I will leave an answer with your solution and explain a bit why it's wrong to use it in general and why my corner-case is ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnaLizaPandac gave me the proper solution to this problem. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` was what i am looking for, but i want to take a moment to go a bit deeper into why this solution is usually wrong and why i actually need it. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) you can find the docs for this property.

As you should know, `innerHTML` is bad because it exposes your web pages to XSS attacks. Why would i employ this solution though? This page does not contain any shared information with any other user and it doesn't contain any vulnerable inputs. I just needed to decorate my JSON object with a button next to the timestamp, that when clicked, redirects to another public page (like google.com). I believe this behavior doesn't expose my app to XSS and solves my problem in a simple elegant way.

I hope i am now wrong with regard to how dom-based XSS works, in case i misunderstood something, leave a comment.

Comment: AFAIK, that's how it works, but while your application may not be vulnerable right now, you have increased the attack surface which can lead to vulnerabilities as your application grows. There are solutions to circumvent most cases of using innerHTML unless you receive actual dynamic HTML from your server that can differ in its structure a lot. There might be a solution in my updated answer if I did get you correctly this time.

Answer (score 0):

Edeph,

I may be misdiagnosing the problem you are experiencing since I cannot see the entire React component that is misbehaving.

However, based on what you described, I believe the problem is that you are colocating both JSX (i.e., `<button>action!</button>`) and javascript code. This is certainly doable and a common usecase for React; however, it would need to be done some way similar to this:

```
myJson.timestamp = myJson.timestamp + "( " + newDate(parseInt(myJson.timestamp) * 1000) + " )

const MyButton () {
  return (
    <div>
      {myJson.timestamp}
      <button>action!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The key here is JSX expressions should always be enclosed in parens, and JS expressions colocated with JSX need to be enclosed in curly brackets.

I hope this is helpful.

### Rendering components from an array

If you have an array of timestamps, you can render the button component like so:

```
return myTimestamps.map(timestamp => {
  const myButton () {
    return (
      <div>
        {timestamp}
        <button>action!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will result in a column of timestamps, each with a button.

Comment: Hi! Perhaps i wasn't super clear in my example. I need to display the button inline in the parsed JSON that has many more lines. While your solution is ok, it show the button after the whole JSON which is not what i needed.

Comment: @Edeph, sorry about the misunderstanding. If `myJson.timestamp` is the result of the concatenation of several timestamps, it may be better to turn that into an array of timestamps instead. That way, using the same `myButton` component above, you could map your array of timestamps, inserting each individual timestamp into its own `myButton` component. Updating my original post based on your clarification.

Comment: I didn't say anything about concatenation. It was just about displaying a button inline rather than as a preset tag (the standard way). setInnerHTML is the solution to what i was looking for though. Check out the comment to my question, there is a code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

I would actually like to ask a question in the comments to give you a full answer but I've still not enough reputation to do so.

You have to use the following attribute: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: {yourHtmlAsString}}` like this:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: thisIsMyCopy}}></div>
    );
}
```

Here's a working sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v8x56yv52l

Having said that, there are ways to circumvent this problem in most cases, unless you return dynamically rendered HTML from your server-side app that can differ in its structure a lot. But if the structure of the HTML is mostly the same and only the content changes, you can dynamically render or omit parts of your JSX like this:

```
return (
{props.conditionMet ? <div>props.anyContentYouLike</div> : null}
);
```

You can also build on the above idea and come up with much more complicated solutions:

```
render () {
innerHTML = props.conditionMet ? <div>props.anyContentYouLike</div> : null};
return innerHTML;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What you said about the react way of doing things is very true, as i also stated in my question. But your example is not in line with my question. I needed to display a stringified JSON object with a button next to a specific field (the JSON object can be really really big!). So the JSON is just a single string for the browser and i can't start splitting it up in order to insert that button. Setting the inner HTML is actually a great solution because it allows me to edit my JSON before stringifying and rendering it.

Comment: Sorry, Edeph. As said before, I needed to ask a question to make sure I've understood your question correctly. Yesterday, I still didn't have enough reputation to do so. I've updated the answer and the working sample, although you've already found the solution.